# Cut, Copy & Paste shortcuts were not working

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts

Im using Loki and there are times that i cant simply able to use ***Ctrl+X | Ctrl+V | Ctrl+C*** shortcuts they were simply not working. It works only after i completely restart the whole system.

Please Help.

Comment: Does this happen when using all apps? At one point I was experiencing a similar issue within epiphany, but only epiphany.

Comment: Yes, but it's not consistent . File manager mostly in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had same problems too after a little search i solved. To solve the problem you have to move English up from the options-->keyboard

Comment: But i have only one language pack and that is English-US. Still the problem persists. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

The Language Setup is not complete - click the complete button under Language Settings. Then, ctlr+c and other shortcuts will work as expected